# Подвисания в соединении к Webсерверу

Tags: php, mysql, windows, apache, производительность

Есть сервер, который поднял нам сисАдмин. Поднят на локалке http://192.168.0.120
Он на Винде, там крутится связка Апач+MySQL.

И развернут код системы, в которой пытаемся работать.

max_execution_time = 10

В процессе работы на сервере возникают некие "Фризы". Они заключаются в том, что одновременно все клиенты чтолибо запрашивающие с сервера получают "крутящееся колесико ожидающего ответ" в броузере.

После чего все одновременно и быстро получают все ответы, которые успели "накликать"-"назапрашивать с сервера".

В обычное время - время отклика страницы 0-3 секунды, в зависимости от "тяжести запросов".

Ни до, ни после, ни во время "Фризов" - загрузка процов, MySQL (он просто спит), ни сети - НУЛЕВЫЕ.

Куда копать - совершенно не понятно. Что можно смотреть? Где ковырять?

Comment: Откройте консоль в браузере на вкладке Network и посмотрите тайминги при «подвисшем» запросе. На какой стадии запроса провисания?

Answer (score 0):

Винда не серверная? Тогда один из вариантов - ограничение на кол-во одновременных соединений.

Comment: Винда серверная.. сейчас поставлю задачу СисАдмину - проверить колво одновременных подключений. Спасибо!

Comment: Вообще надо начать с мониторинга доступности сервера - хотя бы пинг в течении длительного времени. Возможны именно аппаратные сетевые проблемы - роутер, сетевая карта, кабель в конце концов.

Comment: Мне тоже кажется что это сетевые проблемы. СисАдмин - говорит что все хорошо работает. Однако завтра попробую Пинг в этот момент запустить. Спасибо!

Comment: Пинг покажет проблемы только если там совсем всё ни к чёрту. Вам бы порт коммутатора помониторить, к коему прицеплен сервер, желательно вживую (отзеркалить, например) и с высокой дискретностью.

Comment: Пинг прекрасно покажет провалы связи от неск сек. Но конечно, это не тот метод, который даст много инфы. Просто было предложено как самое простое. Как одно из направления поиска проблем.